# C# window Form , that run two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day guys, I checked for previous question, yes i saw them, but it was not really solving my problems.

I am writing an application that has two forms, there is a mainForm and Password form.

The form is for scanning two code and match if they are equal. you scan the first code and then the second code. If they Match it pop-up the green lights to show that they match. If the code does not match it pop-up a red light and a Password form at the same time and locks the form textbox to ReadOnly for supervisor to verify what the user has scanned.

It is doing all this.

The problem is i want when the supervisor enter Password it must show the form again so that the user can continue scanning, it is doing this. But the thing is when it open a new form, the one at the back that was locked it does not disapear. i tried to reset the form, it does not work. Please help in this.

```
//object references of the Main Form
MainForm fm=new MainForm();

if ((txtPassword.Text =="This"
{

    fm.BringToFront();

    //Reset the form to a normal state
    fm.lblResult.Visible = false;
    fm.txtResult.Visible = false;
    fm.chkMtn.Checked = false;
    fm.chkVodacom.Checked = false;

    //Clear the textBox of the form
    fm.txtMainFormScan1.Text="";
    fm.txtMainFormScan2.Text="";

    set the focus on the fist Scan
    fm.txtFirstScan.Focus();
 }

The code above does not work. now i am using the one below.

if ((txtPassword.Text =="ThisPassword")
{
    lblInstructPassword.Text = "Password correct";
    txtPassword.Text = "";
    fm.ControlBox = true;
    //fm.Activate();
    this.Hide();    //This Close the Password form
    fm.Show();
    fm.chkMtn.Checked = true;
}
```

Even when i use the //fm.ShowDialog, i cannot win. I also tried to use the Mutex to allow only one instance of an application to run. result are Zero. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just write a method "ResetForm()" in your main form, and call it from your password form ?

Comment: If this application is going to be very large, consider using WPF with the MVVM pattern instead of winforms.  It provides more power & flexiblity.

Comment: Is not going to be big, its main function is to solve only one problem, Matching to minimize the error that users do, when scanning manually.

Comment: Aboc, i just tried to make a ResetForm() method and call it on password form. still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of work that .Net should be doing for you.

All else being mutable details, your real problem is this:

- You have a working form that compares two values.
- If the comparison result is false, you need a *modal* window to appear to prompt for a password.
- If the password is correct, you need the first form to be editable again and the password form to disappear.

You were on the right path using `ShowDialog()`, as this does disable the window that fires the command to show the dialog.  You need your password logic to be a part of that dialog form, not the parent form.  This will allow you to return a `DialogResult` `enum` value to the parent form (if any value at all) and get you around the needless `Focus()` tossing.

If you want the calling form to disappear and reappear when you do this, wrap the call to your form's `ShowDialog()` call in `this.Hide()` and `this.Show()`

Comment: Yes, But when the first form show, by using this.showDialog() the password form Hide. but when i close the first form that just show. i am going to see that form that had an error when there is mismatch.

Comment: Yes, the second form does everything.

Comment: Create a property in your second form that contains the changes, or put a method in the parent form that is Public and can be called by the child form to pass the value.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbb72544-6386-4a9f-8b4d-f1085e324b09/pass-value-from-child-to-parent-form?forum=csharpgeneral